# Is GPS tracker legal after microphone removal? (Germany)

Tags: germany, is-x-legal, recording

As I understand it, the possession of GPS trackers with a listening function is prohibited in Germany. Meaning that the environment of the tracker can be listened to by a built-in microphone.

Suppose someone owns and uses a GPS tracker with a listening function. And the person opens the tracker, physically removes the microphone - e.g. by cutting off the microphone cables and removing the microphone. Would it then be legal to own and use the tracker without the microphone?

The listening function would still be available in the tracker software, but without the microphone it would be impossible to listen to anything.

https://www.bundesnetzagentur.de/DE/Fachthemen/Telekommunikation/Unternehmenspflichten/Datenschutz/MissbrauchSendeanlagen/start.html (in German)

https://www.bundesnetzagentur.de/SharedDocs/Pressemitteilungen/DE/2018/20180405_GPStracker.html (in German)

Comment: I suppose you are a company, because the TTDSG only applies to companies or persons rendering services or providing goods in Germany, § 1 Ⅲ 1 TTDSG. As a company you can afford hiring a lawyer. Please do so.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt
I am not a company, I am a private person and the question refers to private use. I am a layman, but as I understand it, the ban on possession applies to private individuals: https://www.bundesnetzagentur.de/DE/Vportal/TK/Produkte/spionagegeraete/start.html

Comment: @PJT The site you point to there DOES contain the answer: "In vielen Fällen konnten die Smartwatches durch Deaktivierung der Abhörfunktion rechtskonform umgerüstet werden." - the law examined doesn't care for GPS but for voice or video/photo.

Comment: @Trish Thanks, the phrase is somewhat hidden in the carousel on the website and I must have missed it.
The sentence is a good indication.